# Does a homogeneous oscillating electric field produce a magnetic field?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, maxwell-equations

I am working on a homework problem that says an electron in a continuous laser field can be modeled as experiencing a homogeneous oscillating electric field $\vec{E}(\vec{r},t)=\cos \omega t \ \hat {z}$.

It then proceeds to say that a suitable gauge choice is magnetic potential $\vec{A}=0$ and electric potential $\phi(\vec r,t) = -\cos \omega t \ \hat {z} \cdot \vec r$.

This means that the magnetic field $\vec B=0$.

But Maxwell's equation $$\mathbf{\nabla \times B} = \mu_0 \mathbf{j} + \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial \mathbf{E}}{\partial t}$$
says that a changing electric field will produce a nonzero curl of the magnetic field so $\vec B$ cannot be zero.

What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: Why would B = 0?

Comment: You are correct. You have just proven that the pre-supposed approach $\phi(\vec{r},t) = -\cos(\omega t)\hat{\vec{z}}\cdot\vec{r}$ and $\vec{A}(\vec{r},t)=\vec{0}$ is wrong.

Comment: @ggcg I guess it is because $\vec{A}$ is zero and $B = \nabla \times A$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, what you're saying is that a homogeneous electric field $\vec{E}(\vec{r},t)=\cos \omega t \ \hat {z}$ in vacuum requires you to have a magnetic field that satisfies
$$
\nabla \times \mathbf{B} =\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial \mathbf{E}}{\partial t},
$$
giving you a non-homogeneous magnetic field, which would then require the electric field to satisfy
$$
\nabla \times \mathbf{E} = -\frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t},
$$
that therefore needs an inhomogeneous electric field, in conflict with your initial assumption? Or, in other words, you're saying that the electric field assumed by the question, $\vec{E}(\vec{r},t)=\cos \omega t \ \hat {z}$, is inconsistent with the Maxwell equations?

If that *is* what you're saying, then: **good!** you're right. That electric field is not, strictly speaking, compatible with the Maxwell equations.

It *is*, however, an excellent and interesting approximation to useful solutions under suitable approximations (specifically, the *dipole approximation*). And, under that approximation, you neglect both the magnetic field and the conflict that this creates with the Ampère-Maxwell law. This obviously means that the fields are not *precisely* correct, and that there is the possibility of non-dipole effects (which come in a hierarchy, starting with magnetic dipole effects and then through electric quadrupole field dependences, and then upwards), but if the system is localized enough then those effects can be completely negligible.